# In opencl how to synchronize the threads with in a if/while block

Tags: opencl

OpenCL standard says using `barrier` inside `if/while` block results undefined behavior. But I don't see a reason why synchronizing threads with in an `if/while` block is not possible; the divergent threads are anyway sequential, so the opencl standard easily can be made to make threads that are only inside the block to wait at a `barrier`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use barriers in control blocks like if/for/while.

Threads are only in lockstep within a warp (32 threads on Nvidia GPUs, 64 threads on AMD GPUs). But a workgroup may consist of multiple warps that can follow different branches, and then all threads across the workgroup are not in lockstep anymore.

Comment: we use barriers only when they are not in lockstep. anyway my workgroup size is equal to wavefrront/warp size

Comment: In this case, avoid the control block entirely (or turn it into an unrolled fixed-length loop), make all threads do the same thing, and apply a mask on the data in local memory. Then you can use barriers too.

Answer (score 0):

> the divergent threads are anyway sequential

That is not guaranteed anywhere in the OpenCL standard.

If it were, there would be no need for [`sub_group_barrier`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_C.html#synchronization-functions).

NVIDIA GPUs with [Independent Thread Scheduling](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/volta-tuning-guide/index.html#independent-thread-scheduling) (sm_70 and later devices) is a good example of a mainstream hardware which does not execute all threads (work-items) in a lock-step within a warp (sub-group).

Additionally, in the absence synchronization primitives, compilers are not required to make local (or global) memory writes visible to other threads. Even if threads *are* executed in lock-step, the compiler is free to move around memory operations as it pleases, breaking the common assumptions around lock-step execution, unless a barrier (or a memory fence) is added.

> In opencl how to synchronize the threads with in a if/while block

As ProjectPhysX suggested, you have to break your `if`:

```c
bool condition = /* something */
if (condition) {
   do_one();
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
if (condition) {
   do_two();
}
```

The compiler might optimize things if the target hardware offers any lock-step guarantees.